# Although it's another project php uses the same session to login

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I've got 2 projects I work on right now, but the problem is that since I'm logged into one project the session for the login is saved so when I switch the other project I'm instantly logged in.

Both projects are running on the same server and I save the userID in the Session.

This could get a problematic as soon as I publish the projects and have more user accounts.

Comment: What do you save in Session to save if someone is logged in? Do those projects run on the same (local) webserver?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We can't help without any code or any technical information about your application(s).  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Will the projects be under the same domain name in production? Are you using the same domain/hostname locally?

Comment: Yeah its running on the same server and I save the userID in the Session

Comment: If everything is under the same domain name and port then as far as PHP and the browser is concerned it's all one application. Whether you logically view it as two projects is irrelevant. If they need to be treated as separate then host them separately e.g. on a different port or a subdomain

Comment: okay thank you for ur answer :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your projects are hosted under the same domain name and port then as far as PHP and the browser is concerned it's all one application, and therefore they will share a single Session.

Whether you logically view it as two projects is irrelevant to that. If they need to be treated as separate then host them separately e.g. on a different port or a subdomain - you can do this on your local webserver for development / testing, as well as on the live server.