# multiple php websites sharing same localhost, affecting each others login functionality

Tags: php, session, localhost

I have two different websites sharing same localhost (shared hosting), although I have used sessions, still get some problems. for example, the dashboards are always accessible even if not logged in. I thought I have to use different session_id the separate them , so they dont affect each other. still not working. here is my code

**first site**

```
session_start();
    $_SESSION['session_id']="web1";
        if (isset($_SESSION['nameofuser'])){
            header('Location:adminaccessdashboard.php');
        }
```

**second site**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['session_id']="web2";
        if (isset($_SESSION['nameofuser'])){
            header('Location:adminaccessdashboard.php');
        }
    include('dbconfig.php');
?>
```

**logout for both sites**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['session_id']);
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:adminaccesslogin.php');
?>
```

Comment: Are they sharing the same localhost domain, or do you have a local domain mapped out for them? Sessions are usually shared within the same domain, so it helps if you can separate them.  test.local, test2.local, test3.local. You can point the domain to your localhost IP in your hosts file (/etc/host for Mac and linux, c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts for windows)

Comment: @aynber thanks for your response.  they are sharing the same localhost domain.

Comment: So _why_ are they sharing the localhost domain, why do you not set up a separate VirtualHost for each one of them?

Comment: I have a reseller hosting account (shared hosting) where I can host a few websites. I think this is why all websites are on the same localhost.

Comment: Your localhost setup has nothing to do with what your shared hosting is like. You can choose to set up your localhost any way you want. In this case you need to separate the sites into local subdomains so they don't share the same session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Although it's another project php uses the same session to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379289/although-its-another-project-php-uses-the-same-session-to-login)

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one session for each domain. Your two websites are considered one by your PHP server.

In development, one way to workaround would be to change the key of `$_SESSION['nameofuser']`, such that it is different for each website.

In production, if you are going to launch the website in separate domains or sub-domain, it should not be a problem.